# getting all checked checkboxes and creating li elements with them is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, checkbox, createelement, label-for

I am trying to get all checked checkboxes and create li elements with them. I want the li elements to show up as soon as the checkboxes are checked.
And can I do that without using value attribute in input? I already looked up there is a way to do that with value but that doesn't work with my code.

I have this code

```js
const checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input').type == 'checkbox';

function getChecked() {
    let checked = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        let checkbox = checkboxes[i];
        
        if (checkbox.checked) {
            const rightBox = document.getElementsByClassName('main-container-2')[0];
            const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
            rightBox.appendChild(newDiv);
            
            const ul = document.createElement('ul');
            newDiv.appendChild(ul);
            const li = document.createElement('li');
            ul.appendChild(li);

            const label = document.createElement('label');
            li.innerHTML = label.innerHTML;
          }
        }

        return checked;
    };

getChecked();
```

```html
<div class="article-main">
  <div class="article-left">
      <div>
          <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
          <label for="checkbox1">Onion</label>
      </div>
      <div>
          <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">
          <label for="checkbox2">Spring Onion</label>
      </div>
      <div>
          <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3">
          <label for="checkbox3">Egg</label>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This image is my goal.
[image]

Comment: did you ask yourself what's inside the `checkboxes` variable? I mean you are setting its value as a booelan and then you tried to loop over it? please search how to add a change event handler and how to correctly select elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give you an example for your reference:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  const checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
  for (let i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
    let checkBox = checkBoxes[i];
    checkBox.addEventListener("click", e => {
      if (e.target.checked) {
        const rightBox = document.getElementsByClassName('main-container-2')[0];
        const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        rightBox.appendChild(newDiv);

        const ul = document.createElement('ul');
        newDiv.appendChild(ul);
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        ul.appendChild(li);

        let l=e.target.nextElementSibling;
        li.innerHTML = l.innerHTML;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="article-main">
  <div class="article-left">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
      <label for="checkbox1">Onion</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">
      <label for="checkbox2">Spring Onion</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3">
      <label for="checkbox3">Egg</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main-container-2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your checkboxes select was wrong, so I fixed it in the first place.
You should add a `onclick` function to all of your checkboxes.
Inside that function you should empty the list and loop trough all checkboxes.
When a checkbox is checked, then add a `li` to your list.

The code below works.

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

function getChecked() {
    let checked = [];
    const ul = document.getElementById('ingredients');
    ul.innerHTML = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        let checkbox = checkboxes[i];
        if (checkbox.checked) {
            const li = document.createElement('li');
            li.innerHTML = document.querySelector('label[for="' + checkbox.id + '"]').textContent.trim();
            ul.appendChild(li);
         }
      }
      return checked;
};
```

```html
<div class="article-main">
  <div class="article-left">
      <div>
          <input type="checkbox" onclick="getChecked()" id="checkbox1">
          <label for="checkbox1">Onion</label>
      </div>
      <div>
          <input type="checkbox" onclick="getChecked()" id="checkbox2">
          <label for="checkbox2">Spring Onion</label>
      </div>
      <div>
          <input type="checkbox" onclick="getChecked()" id="checkbox3">
          <label for="checkbox3">Egg</label>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<br/>
your ingredients
<ul id="ingredients">


</ul>
```